# Capturar trama, guardarla en memoria y mostrarla en lcd

Tags: c, programación-bajo-nivel, ccs, pic

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una app en `android` que envía una `string` a un módulo bluetooth HC06 y es recogido por un pic 16f883.

He creado una interrupción que hace que cuando llega la trama la muestre en el lcd, pero no sé cómo puedo capturarla, guardarla en un buffer y ésta a su vez guardarla en memoria.

```
#include <16F883.h>
#fuses HS,NOWDT,PROTECT,NOLVP
#use delay(clock=20000000)
#use  rs232(baud=9600, xmit=PIN_C6,rcv=PIN_C7)

#include <flex_lcd.c>
#include <stdlib.h>

//FUNCIONES
void inicio();

//VARIABLES
char mivariable;
int i;
int contador=1;

//INTERRUPCION
#INT_RDA   // Interrupccion  USART
void RDA_isr()
{
    output_high(pin_A2);
    if(contador==16){
        contador=1;
        printf(lcd_putc, "f");
        lcd_gotoxy(1,1);
        printf(lcd_putc,"BLUETOOTH_2");
    }
    mivariable = getc();

    lcd_gotoxy(contador,2);
    lcd_putc(mivariable);
    contador++;
    output_low(PIN_A2);
}

void main()
{
    inicio();
    while (true)
    {

    }
}

//INICIO LCD CON CARGA....
void inicio(){
    enable_interrupts(INT_RDA);
    enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
    delay_ms(100);
    lcd_init();
    output_high(pin_A2);
    lcd_gotoxy(1,1);
    printf(lcd_putc, "Loading");
    for(i=1;i<=16;i++){
        lcd_gotoxy(i,2);
        printf(lcd_putc, "*");
        delay_ms(200);
    }
    printf(lcd_putc, "f");
    lcd_gotoxy(1,1);
    printf(lcd_putc,"BLUETOOTH_2");
    output_low(PIN_A2);
}
```

Comment: Quizás no estoy entendiendo bien tu pregunta, pero por lo que se ve en tu código, cada byte que llega al módulo lo almacenas en la variable llamada 'mivariable'. Una vez que lo tenes ahí, podes guardarlo en cualquier otro lado o hacer lo que quieras con él. Lo que se suele hacer al programar microcontroladores es trabajar con buffers circulares ya que no es posible alocar memoria en forma dinámica como se haría en una PC tradicional.